# Another WCF MaxMessageSize error

Tags: .net, wcf

So I ran into the classic "Maximum message size exceeded" error with a WCF service I am working on. Strangely though, setting all the message size settings way up as other posts suggest doesn't seem to do anything; I still get the same error.

Here is my server config. The client isn't .net, so there is no client config.

Any ideas?

```
 <services>
        <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="HTTPMetadataBehavior">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2624" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="WebHttpSettings" contract="IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HTTPMetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
            httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />            
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>        
    </behaviors>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WebHttpSettings" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">                  
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Comment: as an aside you can remove the mex endpoint as REST services don;t support WS-MetadataExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this fix won't work for everyone, but for me I made my configuration the default for webHttp by omitting the name and that worked. Here is the revised config.

```
 <services>
        <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="HTTPMetadataBehavior">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2624" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMyService" />
        </service>
    </services>
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HTTPMetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
            httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />            
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>        
    </behaviors>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">                  
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more setting in the service behaviour:

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I still get The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. in the trace logs.

Comment: You have to do it on the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your actual service name isn't MyService by rather it is in a namespace.

Assuming you are using .NET 4 the actual service is picking up a default endpoint with the default binding settings or 65536. Change the name in the service element to be the fully qualified type name of the service implementation class

Comment: The actual file is uses fully qualified names; I just whitewashed them for the post. Also the services work with smaller datasets, so I know the basic configuration works.

Comment: Well with the default endpoint (assuming you are using a WebServiceHost) the code would work for smaller datasets. Are you using VB.NET or C# as VB.NET also has the project name in hte fully qualified name of the service

Comment: Set the endpoint to require transport security - that should show up pretty quickly if you are actually using that part of the configuration

Comment: I'm using C#. It is definitely using the binding configuration, since when I add <security mode="Transport"></security> I get the following trace error: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress

Comment: ok cool - can you turn on tracing and see if it gives any insight as to what exactly is going bang?

Comment: As I mention in my reply to Christian above, tracing is already on. All it has is The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: Looks like you're self hosting - after you create the ServiceHost can you look to see what the MaxReceivedMessageSize is on the host.Description.Endpoints[0]?

Comment: I'm not self hosting; it is the Visual Studio dev server, not IIS right now, but it is just a .svc file, a code behind, the interface class and the web.config. Standard WCF project type.